# Python program for factorial coming up with an error

Tags: python, functional-programming, factorial

I was trying to write a basic factorial program to get some practice in python and i came up with this error for the following code. Any help would be appreciated.

```
def factorial(x):
    x = raw_input(":")
    if x == 0:
        return 1
    else: 
        return x * factorial(x-1)
```

when i run this program through the terminal, it gives me the following error:

**Line 1: syntax error near the unexpected token '('

line 1: def factorial(x)**

Comment: You have a incorrect indentation , you need to correct it first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to indentation mistakes, you need to move this line out of the function,

```
x = raw_input(":"),
```

or you have to input a number at every level of recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Using a recursive function you should not use the raw_input inside the function, It will degrade the whole logic of the function, So the input thing must be done outside the recursive function. And the other thing you need to take care is that the `raw_input()` function always returns a `String` so we explicitly need to convert it to `Integer` type, and you are done.

```
def factorial(x):
    if x == 0 or x==1:
        return 1
    else: 
        return x * factorial(x-1)

number = int(raw_input(":"))
print factorial(number)
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, but the error is coming up in line 1, that is what is stopping my code from executing which is not making sense to me

Comment: @sanster9292 It is working perfectly on my machine and printing `120` for factorial(5)